# Using yq to traverse a list in Almquist shell

Tags: yaml, sh, yq

I have this example of a YAML file, which includes a variable number of elements in the 'containers' list and in the 'networks' list of each container.

```
lab_name: practica0
containers:
- name: vm1
  image: rys
  networks:
  - 1
- name: router
  image: rys
  networks:
  - 1
  - 2
- name: vm2
  image: rys
  networks:
  - 2
```

I wanna loop through the 'containers' and the 'networks' arrays getting all the values, but I don't know exactly how to do it. I tried using a for loop and a shell variable, like this `yq eval '.containers[$i].name' example.yaml`, but it didn't work. I tried enclosing `$i` between double quotes and escaping them as specified here https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/468#issuecomment-752114840, but still no luck. I'm using Go yq by the way, and I have to use Almquist Shell instead of bash so I can't use things like `readarray`. Thank you

EDIT: For example, my desired output would be something as simple as this:

```
vm1
rys
1

router
rys
1
2

vm2
rys
2
```

Comment: Your yaml isn't properly indented, could you please [edit] your question to fix that?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I believe it is now fixed. Thanks

Comment: Yes, could you also add the desired output?

Comment: Done, I have added a pretty simple example of what I want.

Comment: So you want raw string output, no yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much simpler solution: I wasn't using the quotes around the variable as I should. `yq eval '.containers['"$i"'].name' example.yaml` works perfectly for me. Anyway, thanks for your answers and comments!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
yq e '.containers | map([ .name, .image, .networks[] ])' input
```

to create a list of values you desire:

```yaml
- - vm1
  - rys
  - 1
- - router
  - rys
  - 1
  - 2
- - vm2
  - rys
  - 2
```

---

Not sure what the prevered way is to convert this into a new-line separated string. But with some additional logic, we can get the desired output using the `sed` and `tr` utilities.

Use `@tsv` to let yq create a tab separated value, then we use some common shell utilities to convert that to the desired output

1. `sed G` places a newline after each line
2. `tr '\t' '\n'` replaces the tab with an other newline

```
yq e '.containers | map([ .name, .image, .networks[] ]) | @tsv' input | sed G | tr '\t' '\n'
```

```
vm1
rys
1

router
rys
1
2

vm2
rys
2
```

Comment: If the intent is ultimately to loop over these, try `yq ... | while IFS= read -r name image networks; for network in $networks; do echo "name" "$name" "image" "$image" "network" "$network"; done; done` or maybe `IFS='(tab)'` if the values might contain whitespace but not tabs, and you use tabs as separators.

Comment: jq has `join("\n")`. Combined with `--raw-output`/`-r`, you don't have JSON quoting of the string. Maybe yq has something similar?